# (Python) Error 401 when trying to access course work using Google Classroom API

Tags: python, google-classroom

I'm pretty new to google apis, so I was messing around with the classroom api. I used the sample code and it worked fine for getting a list of courses, however when i try to access a list of coursework, topics, or announcements for a class, I get the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/courseId/courseWork?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.">
```

I put a placeholder for course id in my program for privacy reasons, but this problem happens when i use a real course id. This is what shows when I click the link in my console:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I tried clicking on the link in that error, but it wasn't helpful at all. I'm pretty confused by the fact that my console gives me an error 404, while the link gives me an error 401. Forgive me if they're the same thing. I also tried using two other accounts, neither of which worked. I thought that I might've done something wrong with my code, but I tested it with the sample for coursework and that didn't work either. It is important to mention that I'm not an administrator, rather a student trying to build something that could help me. I also thought it was a problem with the token, but as mentioned above, I tried with other accounts, so I shouldn't have needed to use the refresh token. My program was written in python.
My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students']

def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    # I put a placeholder for courseId, but I can provide an id to a test course if needed
    results = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId="courseId").execute()
    courses = results.get('courseWork', [])

    if not courses:
        print('No coursework found.')
    else:
        print('Coursework:')
        for courseWork in cwork:
            print(courseWork['name'])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I might be passing the wrong parameters to the function, but I looked over the sample and I don't think so. This is kind of unrelated to the question but if anyone could show me how to use the refresh tokens, that would be great. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct CourseId, and that the `courseWorkStates` corresponds to the course work state. Try with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list)

Comment: @Jescanellas Thank you for the help! The problem was that I wasn't using the correct course ID. I thought you would get it the same way as a google doc, but I needed to make my program print it for this.

Comment: Does tat mean that you managed to make it work? If so please try to post an answer so other people may benefit and upvote your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code was that I was using the wrong classroom ID. Unlike google docs/sheets, you cannot find the classroom ID in the address. For me, I went through each course and wrote code to print the ID, which I substituted into my program to list the coursework. This was my finished code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me' , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Classroom API.
    Prints the names of the first 10 courses the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    rs = service.courses().list(pageSize='1').execute()
    courses = rs.get('courses' , [])
    i = 0
    if not courses:
        print('No coursework found.')
    else:
        for course in courses:
            a = course['id']
            results = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=a, 
                pageSize='1').execute()
            cwork = results.get('courseWork', [])
            for courseWork in cwork:
                print(courseWork['title'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It only prints one item from one course for testing purposes, but changing the page size will change that.